# What is the difference between request header 'cache-control' field and response header 'cache-control'?

Tags: http, http-headers

Title itself describes the question. I am curious to know what is the difference between request header `Cache-control` and response header `Cache-control` fields.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on each directives (`public`, `private`, `no-cache`, `no-store`, ...). For example, the `#field-name` argument is defined for the `no-cache` directive if it is used for response but not for request.

Read "7.2.1.  Request Cache-Control Directives" and "7.2.2.  Response Cache-Control Directives" in [draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-25](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-25) for details. It is still a draft but I think it is clearer than RFC 2616.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234 is also a good  document explaining the `Cache-Control` and a few other HTTP headers (such as `Warning`) used along the cache.